# stacking multiple columns into single column with single value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stack, melt

```r
ID Time  U1 U2 U3 U4
1  20     1  0  0  0 
2  20     0  1  0  0
3  20     0  0  1  0 
4  20     0  0  0  1
```

And I would need to keep it like:

```
ID Time   U 
1  20    U1 
2  20    U2 
3  20    U3 
4  20    U4
```

I tried with:

```r
X_D <- as.data.frame(X)
X_new <- stack(X_D, select = -c(ID, Time))
```

Comment: You can simply use the `pivot_longer` function from tidyr package.

Comment: Apart from that, please provide a reproducible exmaple, e.g. by doing sth. like `dput(head(YOURDATA))` in R and copying the result here.

Comment: You can use something like `subset(cbind(df[c(1, 2)], stack(df[-c(1, 2)])), values == 1, select = c("ID", "Time", "ind"))`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4, Time = 20, U1 = c(1,0,0,0), U2 = c(0,1,0,0), U3 = c(0,0,1,0), U4 = c(0,0,0,1))

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = 3:6, names_to = "U") %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  select(-value)
```